# Django - Implementing user actions with no login, using only GET parameters

Tags: django

I'm writing an classified ads website, I need that the users renew the Ads only clicking in a URL that I will send by email. What cautions should I have implementing a system like this? I've searched on the web but didn't find examples of an implementation like this.

Can someone give some clues about the right path to do this?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, [SQL Injection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev) will be a major thing to worry about, especially when using obvious get parameters.

Second, you will want non-personally identifying info in the GET parameters. You will **NOT** want short ids such as 123456 as these are VERY EASILY guessed. A GUID (example 412dc535-03dd-4887-b702-02c8b85e8891, you would remove the - of course) is great for this.

Third, you will want some sort of basic verification that it is in fact the user that originated the request. Have each email have its own ID for the one click action, perhaps a GUID (long string of random characters), and make them expire after some time (a few days). Keep track of each email link separately and what they're supposed to do, so that someone couldn't just figure out the ID of someone's ad and keep running it over and over.

~Christian

Comment: +1 Ha! I was just going to comment on this and I saw the "edit" line appear above your answer. UUIDs/GUIDs are definitely the way to go. Add a record in the DB so there's an expiration date associated with them, and then flag them once they've been used.

Comment: I tend to edit things immediately after posting a general summary.